# cannot play video at high frame rate

Tags: java

Context
      I am trying to create a video player in Jcreator but problem is it gives following error

> ```
>   --------------------Configuration: newPlayer - JDK version 1.7.0_55 <Default> - <Default>--------------------
>   Unable to handle format: mpeglayer3, 44100.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, LittleEndian, Signed, 6000.0 frame rate, FrameSize=32768 bits
> Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@15419025
> Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@15419025
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at newPlayer.Pla(newPlayer.java:48)
>     at newPlayer.main(newPlayer.java:59)
> ```

```
Process completed. 




    import java.awt.*;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class newPlayer {
        JFrame frame;
        Player play;
        URL url;
        JFileChooser chooser;
        public void Pla()
        {
            frame=new JFrame();

            frame.setSize(1500,1500);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            chooser=new JFileChooser();
            int i=chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(i==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION);
            {
                url=null;
            }
            try
            {
            url=chooser.getSelectedFile().toURI().toURL();
            }
            catch ( MalformedURLException malformedURLException )
     {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not create URL for the file" );
     } 
     try
     {
            play=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(url);
     }
     catch ( CannotRealizeException cannotRealizeException ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not realize media player.");
        } 
     catch ( IOException iOException )
     {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error reading from the source" );
     }
     catch ( NoPlayerException noPlayerException ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No media player found");
        } 

            Component view=play.getVisualComponent();
                //adds video component
            Component ctrl=play.getControlPanelComponent();
            frame.add(view,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.add(ctrl,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            play.start();

        }
        public static void main(String[]argo)
        {
            newPlayer f=new newPlayer();
            f.Pla();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing the picture, change the frame rate, do all the stuff just for being safe. Also, take into consideration that Java might lack some cutting edge functionalities as native Android or Flutter.

Answer (score -1):

Reading the error message...

> Unable to handle format: mpeglayer3, 44100.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, LittleEndian, Signed, 6000.0 frame rate, FrameSize=32768 bits

Your video fromat is wrong.

> what video formats are supported by JMF.ps

Well, let's try [looking it up](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+video+formats+are+supported+by+JMF.ps&oq=what+video+formats+are+supported+by+JMF.ps).

The first link takes us [to a table  of supported formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html).

Comment: i have used createPlayer instead of createrealized player and now its giving noPlayerException :(.pls check the code if anything is wrong with it.i used createrealized player too but it says no player found